# Why I cannot send the image into server(backend), getting either "the summited file is empty" or "null"?

Tags: android, kotlin, backend

I have a task to send all user info as `Multipart.Body` to server and I have an endpoint for it. When I used Postman to check the sending of image to server and it works there, however I cannot find the thing I do wrong.
In logcat I got either `{"profile picture":["The submitted file is empty."]}`
or
if in `prepareImagePart` function instead of `profile_picture` I write "photo" it updates all user info (send it) but photo sends as "null"

```
nterface UserDataAPI {
    @Multipart
    @PUT("v1/profile/update/")
    fun updateUserInfo(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Part("username") user_name: RequestBody,
        @Part("name") name: RequestBody,
        @Part profile_picture: MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part("bio") bio: RequestBody,
        @Part("link") dateOfBirth: RequestBody,
        @Part("is_private") isPrivate: RequestBody,
    ): Call<Any>
}

class UserDataViewModel(private val userDataRepository: UserDataRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _updateStatus = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val updateStatus: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _updateStatus

    private val _userInfo = MutableLiveData<UserOwnInfo?>()
    val userInfo: LiveData<UserOwnInfo?> = _userInfo

    fun updateUserInfo(
        context: Context,
        token: String,
        username: String,
        name: String,
        profile_picture: Uri,
        bio: String,
        link: String,
        isPrivate: Boolean
    ) {
        val imageFile = ImageConverter.getFile(context, profile_picture)
        if (imageFile != null) {
            val imagePart = prepareImagePart(imageFile)
            val imageParts = imagePart

            Log.d("UpdateUserInfo", "Profile Picture: ${imageFile.absolutePath}")

            userDataRepository.updateUserInfo(
                token,
                username,
                imageParts,
                name,
                bio,
                link,
                isPrivate,
                object :
                    Callback<Any> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Any>, response: Response<Any>) {
                        _updateStatus.value = response.isSuccessful
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>, t: Throwable) {
                        _updateStatus.value = false
                    }
                })
//        }
        }
    }

    private fun prepareImagePart(imageFile: File): MultipartBody.Part {
        val requestFile = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_picture", imageFile.name, requestFile)
    }
}

class UserDataRepository(private val userDataAPI: UserDataAPI) {

    fun updateUserInfo(
        token: String,
        username: String,
        profile_picture: MultipartBody.Part,
        name: String,
        bio: String,
        link: String,
        isPrivate: Boolean,
        callback: Callback<Any>
    ) {
        val usernameRequestBody = username.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
        val nameRequestBody = name.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
        val bioRequestBody = bio.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
        val linkRequestBody = link.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
        val isPrivateRequestBody = isPrivate.toString().toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)

        val token = "$token"

        userDataAPI.updateUserInfo(
            token,
            usernameRequestBody,
            nameRequestBody,
            profile_picture,
            bioRequestBody,
            linkRequestBody,
            isPrivateRequestBody
        ).enqueue(callback)
    }
}
    private fun updateUser() {
        val username = binding.etUsername.text.toString()
        val name = binding.etName.text.toString()
        val bio = binding.etBio.text.toString()
        val link = binding.etLink.text.toString()
        val switch = false

        val token = Holder.token
        val authHeader = "Bearer $token"

        selectedImageUri?.let { imageUri ->
            val imageFile = ImageConverter.getFile(requireContext(), imageUri)
            if (imageFile != null) {
                val imagePart = prepareImagePart(imageFile)
                val imageParts = imagePart

                userDataViewModel.updateUserInfo(
                    requireContext(),
                    token = authHeader,
                    username = username,
                    profile_picture = imageUri,
                    name = name,
                    bio = bio,
                    link = link,
                    isPrivate = false
                )

                Log.d("TokenCheck", imagePart.toString())
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error converting image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        } ?: run {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun prepareImagePart(imageFile: File): MultipartBody.Part {
        val requestFile = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_picture", imageFile.name, requestFile)
    }
```

Comment: Start by replacing `image/*` with the exact MIME type of the content that you are uploading. Beyond that, you might want to show what `ImageConverter.getFile()` does, as that seems like it might not be working as you expect.